# Removing a label from a Symfony form

Tags: symfony

I'm using a Symfony form and I am trying to either remove the label that has appeared or change it to a line of text which accepts spaces. The label in this case is Response a, which is the name of the form.

Entity:

```
protected $responseA;

public function getResponseA()
{
    return $this->responseA;
}

public function setResponseA($responseA)
{
    $this->task = $responseA;
}
```

Controller for the form:

```
$responseA = new Applicant();
$responseA->setResponseA('');

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($responseA)
    ->add('responseA', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => array(
            'Very Acceptable' => '1',
            'Acceptable' => '2',
            'Inappropriate' => '3',
            'Very Inappropriate' => '4'
        ),
    ))
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
    ->getForm();
```

What I would like to remove or change:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Set 'label' value to false](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#label) will suppress the label display.

$responseA = new Applicant();
$responseA->setResponseA('');

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($responseA)
    ->add('responseA', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => array(
            'Very Acceptable'    => '1',
            'Acceptable'         => '2',
            'Inappropriate'      => '3',
            'Very Inappropriate' => '4'
        ),
        'label'   => false,
    ))
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
    ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in the template by ommiting the `form_label` for some fields:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.responseA) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.responseA) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.save) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```